# C# Selenium: Implementing Test UI for Selenium Test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

Just want to ask if implementing a UI for C# Selenium that will filter all my test is possible? Lets say I have Test1, Test2 and Test3. My UI will have a dropdown filter for Regression, Integration, Smoke etc. If I select for example Smoke on the dropdown filter in UI, it will pull the tests that are tagged under 'Smoke' category. My issue is that I dont know what attributes or how to parametarized my test to be under Smoke/Regression or Integration. I am using TextFixture for my tests. Hope someone can enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Category Attributes as outlined at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute

```html
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [Category("LongRunning")]
  public class LongRunningTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for 2 days and trying to get all the test methods by Categories Attribute but no luck. Can someone share to me the implementation for this if there are available methods that can be used? I'm just new in .Net Automation and I'm getting a hard time implementing it.